# How to determine a developer's total contribution to SubVersion?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I'd like to be able to see someone's total lines of code contributed to our application. Say the app is 10k lines of code, I'd like to see the breakdown of how many LOC each developer has committed to the repository. Is there anything for SubVersion to get this kind of info?

Comment: Just out of curiosity...why do you want to count lines of code?

Comment: I'm just curious about certain developer's contribution to the project.

Comment: Ok. Just keep in mind that LOC is very general. You could have a more experienced developer compressing something from 15 lines down to 5...just something to keep in mind.

Comment: I agree completely, this is really just for curiousity. :)

Comment: I would also warn against taking these statistics too seriously, or using them to judge the value of someone's contribution, especially in reference to performance reviews or raises.

Comment: Hey, maybe I'll just quote myself: "I agree completely, this is really just for curiosity."

Comment: @JustinNiessner Not just 15 to 5 lines. Some people do not use generics or code-reducing patterns. I tend to write generic and less code as possible if readability and traceability is still given. So this measurement is not really fact for good programmers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [MPY SVN STATS](http://mpy-svn-stats.berlios.de/) and also [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/) if I remember correctly that should do what you want and much more.

I don't think it can be done with tortoisesvn all the tools that I know are command line tools and I fear some of them linux tools.

Comment: As long as I can run the commandline tools via cygwin, it wouldn't be a problem. I'll take another gander at StatsSVN though.

Comment: Looks like StatSVN (just 2 s's) did what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[`svn blame`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re02.html) can get you started, by prepending the committer's name to each line of source code.

Their example output was

```
$ svn blame http://svn.red-bean.com/repos/test/readme.txt
     3      sally This is a README file.
     5      harry You should read this.
```

So you could do something like

```
cat ./*blamed | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c
```

on a file formed like

```
$ cat b.txt
3 Mark asdf
3 Mark asdf
3 Bill fdas
4 Bill fdas
5 Fred fdfd
```

to get output like

```
$ cat b.txt | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c
      2 Bill
      1 Fred
      2 Mark
```

... but there's probably a cleaner way to do it than that.

Comment: Is that only for a single file though? I'd like something for a whole project.

Comment: The page says `svn blame` works for "the specified files", so I assume you can specify as many files as you'd like.  I don't have svn here so I can't test it out.